# inno setup как задать права на создаваемую директорию в program files

Tags: inno-setup, setup

Как изменить права группы текущего пользователя на создаваемую папку (добавить туда еще изменение и выполнение)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа во время своей работы не должна никак менять Program Files. Все изменяемые данные должны помещаться в профиль пользователя.

Comment: Кроме тех случаев когда нам надо обновить компоненты программы. Ведь не было вопроса должна или нет, спасибо кэп.

Comment: @Ivan - обновление программы должен делать ее инсталлятор, который будет обладать правами администратора, и следовательно, иметь возможность писать в Program Files

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\FullPermissionsDir"; Permissions: everyone-full
```

Но это будет папка вложенная в папку, которую выбрал пользователь для установки приложения. Таком образом рекомендуют создавать только пустые папки, поскольку папки для файлов, указанных в секции `[Files]` создаются автоматически во время установки.